# How to characterize an open ball around $z$ when $f$ is m-strongly convex.

Tags: real-analysis, convex-analysis

Assume that $f$ is a differentiable $m$-strongly convex function as follows:

$$ f(y) \geq f(x) + \left<\nabla f (x),y-x\right>+\frac{m}{2}\|y-x\|^2$$
for all $x,y \in \mathbb{R}^n$.

How can one characterize a neighborhood ($||x-z||<\epsilon$) around a given point $z$ by finding its radius $\epsilon$? In other words, how do we know for every given point $z\in \mathbb{R}^n$ there exist a neighborhood? Also, when it exists, how we can find its radius.

**My try:** For a given $z$ we have the following:

$f(y)  \geq  f(z) - || \nabla f (z)|| \cdot ||y-z|| +\frac{m}{2}\|y-z\|^2$

$\frac{2}{m} \Big(f(y) - f(z) +|| \nabla f (z)|| \cdot ||y-z||\Big) \geq   \|y-z\|^2$

I do not know how argue and convert $f(y) - f(z)$ and manage $||y-z||$ to get an $\epsilon$ as the upper bound.

Comment: I do not understand your question. Is there any relation between the neighborhood and your function $f$?

Comment: @gerw: No. Can you please which part is not understandable?

Comment: For example: "In other words, how do we know for every given point ∈ℝ there exist a neighborhood?" To answer the literal question: "By definition, $\{x \in \mathbb R^n \mid \|x - z \| < 42\}$ is a neighborhood of $z$. Thus, every point possesses a neighborhood. But I think this is not your real question...

Comment: @gerw: I want to know if there is any way to found that 42 based on the gradient at $x$ and $x$ itself?

Comment: Is there any relation that should hold on this neighborhood? This is not stated in your question.

Comment: @gerw: Yes. It should be related to $f(z)$ and its gradient. I want to see if we can have an $\epsilon$ depending on the value of $z$ and its gradient. It is all I have.

Comment: Sorry, but you are wasting my time. I still do not know what you try to achieve with your neighborhood.